# How to show box border for text scanned from image using TextRecognizer

Tags: android, ocr

I'm working on TextRecognizer following this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2016/11/optical-character-recognition-android-ocr/), I want to show the box around words and allow user to select text. Can anyone help me how to show border to words?

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(this, imageUri);
            if (detector.isOperational() && bitmap != null) {

                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();

                SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = detector.detect(frame);

                String blocks = "";
                String lines = "";
                String words = "";
                for (int index = 0; index < textBlocks.size(); index++) {
                    //extract scanned text blocks here
                    TextBlock tBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(index);
                    blocks = blocks + tBlock.getValue() + "\n" + "\n";
                    for (Text line : tBlock.getComponents()) {
                        //extract scanned text lines here
                        lines = lines + line.getValue() + "\n";
                        for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text words here
                            words = words + element.getValue() + ", ";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```